# Manipulating ordering of results of whereis command

Tags: shell, path

Right now, if I type `whereis` on an executable that I'm interested in knowing the location, I get back several results where this software is located.  What configuration can be done to get the last result at the front of the list?

If I'm running `whereis gcc`, I may have 5 different versions of `gcc` on the OS, but the highest/most-recent version displays last in the results of `whereis gcc`, so it's not the preferred version of `gcc`.  So even though I have version 7.1 of GCC, running `gcc -v` displays the lowest version that's installed on my box.

Answer (score 1):

`whereis python | sed 's/ /\n/g' | sort | uniq`

Then sort has many options

If you want to reverse the order:

`whereis python | sed 's/ /\n/g' | sort -r | uniq`

```
-r, --reverse
    reverse the result of comparisons
```

if you (could) have some odd binary/source/manual files containing special chars:

```
-i, --ignore-nonprinting
    consider only printable characters
```

Comment: Also, `sort | uniq` can be replaced with `sort -u`